# Как организовать редактирование статьи с картинкой на Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel

Делаю сайт. Есть статьи, для которых в админке есть ресурсный контроллер. В нём можно добавлять новые статьи и редактировать существующие. При добавлении новой всё хорошо: в текстовые поля вводится текст, а в type="file" файл картинки. Файл загружается на сервер, а путь к нему прописывается в таблицу статьи, вместе с остальными данными.

Проблема с редактированием. При вызове edit() появляется форма с правильно заполненными текстовыми полями, но без заполнения поля файла. У него стоит "Файл не выбран". Программно заменять value этого инпута нельзя, это не работает (по соображениям безопасности). И как быть? Я хочу, чтобы при появлении формы редактирования показывался текущий файл и при сохранении (если его никто не трогал) путь к нему сохранялся. Как это сделать?

**Контроллер**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $article = Article::create($request->all());//записываем в базу

    //Загрузка файлов
    $file = $request->file('img');
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move('../public/images/download', $filename);//папка для загрузки изображения
    if ($filename) {
        $article = Article::find($article->id);
        $article->img = 'images/download/' . $filename;
        $article->save();
    }
    return redirect()->route('admin.article.index');
}

public function edit(Article $article)
{
    return view('admin.articles.edit', [
        'article' => $article,   //массив статей
    ]);
}

public function update(Request $request, Article $article)
{
    $article->update($request->except('slug'));
    return redirect()->route('admin.article.index');
}
```

**form.blade.php** (value вставляется, но не влияет на кнопку)

```
@if(isset($article->id))
{{-- Для edit--}}
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="img" placeholder="img"
       value="{{$article->img}}">
@else
{{-- Для create--}}
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="img" placeholder="img"
       value="">
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробую пояснить немного подробнее. В html есть тэг label, который устанавливает связь с полем( в нашем случае input) - http://htmlbook.ru/html/label . При нажатии на label срабатывает инпут. В инпут ничего писать нельзя, в label можно писать что угодно. 
Вам приведен пример:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="img">
текущий файл {{ $article->img }} , для замены выберите другой файл
</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="img" name=”img” >    
</div>
```

который даст следующую картину
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
т.е. у Вас появляется информация о текущем файле и при необходимости можете его поменять на новый

CSS + JS тут для феншуя: например скрыть поле ввода файла или подставить новое значение инпута в label

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="img">
текущий файл {{ $article->img }} , для замены выберите другой файл
</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control my-super-file" id="img" name=”img” >    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-super-file { display:none;}
```

результат 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
видно только текущий файл и при нажатии можно ввести новый(правда старый останется)

путем простешего js вы приводите это все к примерно этому https://codepen.io/AVZ/pen/RwNXEYq

Comment: Что значит " на продакш"? По остальному: сделать проверку на существование данных в инпуте и если там пусто, то игнорировать это поле при перезаписи таблицы (я уже так и сделал в рамках первого костыля). А вот дальше не понял. Если в поле что-то есть, то это "что-то" так и улетает в пост-запросе в контроллер. Никакие js-скрипты применить там нельзя. Если скриптом прописать у value инпута значение, то оно будет проигнорировано, я уже проверял.

Comment: немного обновил инфу, возможно теперь понятней.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно.

Comment: @Ostet, если ответ был получен, закройте вопрос.

Comment: Дурацкий вопрос, но... как это делается?